# Excel VBA: Cell Value from Macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a Macro that sets the value of a cell from other cell values.
So the Macro sets the value of a cell when I run the code as usual.

But I want the Macro work like a Formula.
So the value of a cell always changes when those cells are change.

Is there any way to do this?
Or Maybe a way to call the Macro from formula?

**Edit: (After Comments)**

Ok. This is what I want from the Macro.

I have Hours:Minutes, and I want to SUM all of them.
The problem is I have negative Hours:Minutes that I've calculated them using the formula below:

```
=TEXT(ABS(H10-E10),"-h:mm")
```

So I have something like this:

```
08:20, 02:10, -03:20, [and so on...]
```

And I want the result:

```
 08 + 02 - 03 = 07
 20 + 10 - 20 = 10
 = 07:10 (The Result)
```

Because we don't have negative Time in Excel, and I have Text instead of Time, so I have to calculate them with ForLoop in VBA.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create user defined functions, check this out: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: Or a regular formula ;)

Comment: @Rory nice comment! This question is surely too vague without any research?

Comment: @Dave, Thanks, That's not what I wanted.

Comment: @Rory, Sorry, I can't use the regular formula. Cause I have to use complex structure in the Macro.

Comment: @JohnCroneh complex is what this site is about - please show us your code so far?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a macro that operates on a `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Formulas can be extremely complex! I suggest you elaborate in your question as to what exactly you need to do.

Comment: @Rory, Thanks. I've just update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple example.  Say your macro changes **A1** based on the value in cells **B1** thru **D1**.

```
Sub MyMac()
    Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value + Range("C1").Value + Range("D1").Value
End Sub
```

We will use an event macro to detect manual changes to any of the input cells and run MyMac.  Put this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("B1:D1")
    If Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call MyMac
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**NOTE:**

This is only good for *Manual* changes to the input cells.  If any of **B1** thru **D1** contained formulas, the *Calculate* event would be used.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Shortcut Notation** method for getting values from range

```
Sub getting_value()

'Static Cell-pointing
    Debug.Print [a1]                      'for referring Active Sheet's cell
    Debug.Print [Sheet1!a1]               'for referring Sheet1's cell 

'Partial Dynamic Cell-pointing
    Debug.Print [a:b].Cells(1,1)               'for referring Range
    Debug.Print [5:5].Cells(1,1)               'for referring Range
    Debug.Print [a:b 5:5].Cells(1,1)           'for referring Intersect

    Debug.Print [a1,a3].Cells(1,1)              'for referring a1 AND a3

    Debug.Print [a1.a3].Cells(1,1)              'for referring a1 TO a3
    Debug.Print [a1..a3].Cells(1,1)             'for referring a1 TO a3
    Debug.Print [a1:a3].Cells(1,1)              'for referring a1 TO a3

'Dynamic Cell-pointing
    Debug.Print [Table1[Column1]].Cells(1,1)   'for referring Table1's column1 
    Debug.Print [NamedRange]                   'for referring Named Range (making named range dynamic by vba -> ThisWorkbook.Names.Add) 

End Sub
```

**Reference**

- [Referring to Range() using shortcut notation : from Mr Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/343178-referring-range-using-shortcut-notation.html)
- [Excel VBA Shortcut Range References : from Excel Hero Blog](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/06/when-working-in-vba-we.html)